# How to keep the nested structure of the fields after selecting part of those with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a structure like this for my AVRO data:

```
{
 info: {
   person: {name:string, surname:string, age:int}
   address: {location:string, street:string, house_number:int}
   work: {job_title:string, salary:string}
 },
 id_card:string
 data_version:int
}
```

and I would like to select only a part of it, for example:

```
df = df.select(['info.person.*', 'info.address.*', 'id_card'])
```

the problem with this line is that the `df` won't carry over the original structure of the data but will "extract" the columns, returning a `df` that will have a column structure like this:

```
name|surname|age|location|street|house_number|id_card
```

but what I need is that the original structure is kept, so that the final `df` would be:

```
info|id_card
```

so I can still run this type of queries `df.select('info.person.name')` or `df.select('info.address.street')` but nothing related to `work` like `df.select('info.work.job_title')`

Is there any way to get that with PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to select a subset of the nested fields in an Avro data and keep the original structure of the data in PySpark.

Instead of using `df.select()`, you would need to use the `df.withColumn()` function, combined with the `pyspark.sql.functions.struct` function, which is used to create a new struct column.You could achieve this by doing something similar to below,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct

df = df.withColumn(
    'info', 
    struct(
        struct(df['info']['person']['name'], df['info']['person']['surname'], df['info']['person']['age']).alias('person'),
        struct(df['info']['address']['location'], df['info']['address']['street'], df['info']['address']['house_number']).alias('address')
    )
)
```

In this way, you're creating a new `'info'` column which is a struct composed of two other structs: `'person'` and `'address'`. This maintains the nested structure of your data but excludes the `'work'` field.

You should now be able to select `'info.person.name'` or `'info.address.street'` but not `'info.work.job_title'`.  this will overwrite the original `'info'` column in the `DataFrame`. If you want to keep the original data as well you can create a new DataFrame or a new column.

Comment: is there a simpler way to import the structure? I mean can I just use `struct(df['info']['person']).alias('person')` to import the whole part? In my case specifying all the single field would be very unpractical because I have hundreds of fields and they also change quite frequently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of Spark more recent than 3.1 you can use [Column.dropFields](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields.html#pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields), the link is full of examples doing exactly this, just make sure to chain the columns to remove multiple fields.

There isn't a native sql alternative, but you can use the Quality sql [drop_field function](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/sqlfunctions/#drop_field) after registering the jar's through the [extension](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/getting_started/#using-the-sql-functions-on-spark-thrift-hive-servers), if sql is needed.